# How can my app jump to iOS default mailbox?

Tags: ios, email

I wanna set a button inside my app that, if clicked, app can jump to the default mailbox of iOS. I want to do this so users can check & send their mails.

Does this function need a private API or is this forbidden by Apple?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: This can't be done with public APIs or for an app meant to be approved by Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **Send** an email from within your app, one of the first 2 answers will work: `MFMailComposeViewController` or using the url scheme `mailto://`.

As for **checking** the users email, there is currently no public way to launch the default iOS mail application. There are however a few 3rd party libraries available to allow you to set up your own mail client, for example [MailCore](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=https://github.com/mronge/MailCore&ei=_nGUUe3eDoXq8QTJ_IGIBA&usg=AFQjCNGRF0K8ynskkjvwp0eFJmajL8IwwA&sig2=ziubOxY6-SlyDq8SWTWJ7Q&bvm=bv.46471029,d.eWU), [remail](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/) or [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-library.asp). I'm sure there are others but you get the idea.

Comment: oops, seems a lot more work to go,will go through the 3rd party libraries you mentioned.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend Chilkat if it weren't for 2 issues: 1.) The static library is around 30MB's! and 2.) It's not free *(although for a single user $99 is fine if your app is heavily dependent on a mail feature)*. But 30MB's is way to big in my opinion.

Comment: It all depends on your need for the library. Take a look at the features and you will have to decide if its the right choice.

Answer (score 4):

This does what you want:

```
let app = UIApplication.shared
if let url = NSURL(string: "message:"), app.canOpenURL(url) {
    app.openURL(url)
}
```

The `canOpenURL` part checks if the user has got at least one email address setup in Mail that they can send/receive from.

Comment: Works really good. Actually opens the mail app without the compose window :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the url scheme like this:

```
NSString *email = @"mailto:?subject=YourSubject&body=MsgBody";
email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Comment: this method provides a way to send mail,but I'd like to open the iOS default mailbox within my apps,I hope I can check my mails just as easy as browsing the pics in pic library.can you suggest another one?or should I rewrite a mailbox client?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `MFMailComposeViewController`? You can set its subject, recipients, message body, the attachment, and then you can present it modally within your app. It will be better too since the user does not need to leave your app.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailViewController setSubject:subjectString];
    [mailViewController setMessageBody:messageString isHTML:YES];
    [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Just remember to set the view controller calling the function above as the delegate of `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` so that you can dismiss the view controller afterwards.

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Apple documentation on this class:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The question asks how an app can send a user to the Mail app so they can check the email in their default account.

Comment: hey,buddy,this is exactly the problem I was talking about,you can use this API to send mail, but not open the mailbox like android apps do.so any idea on open the mailbox just like I can jump to app store within my app,if I click on some ads or update stuff